# Can't add user to a role

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I follow [the MS guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189775.aspx) and they give a specific example as follows.

```
ALTER ROLE Sales ADD MEMBER Barry;
```

However, when I perform corresponding operation, I get an error telling me that "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ADD'" and a line under the keyword *ADD*. When I hover over it, I can see that the tooltip says "Expecting WITH".

As far I can see, *WITH* is used for other alternation that addition of users to roles. So my question is twofold.

1. What can I do to add the user to the role?
2. What's upp with the misguided tooltip?

[Somewhere else on the internet](http://sqlserverplanet.com/security/add-user-to-role), I've seen that the users are added to roles by calling a stored procedure instead. That begs a question what the MSDN link is talking about - as if it's not possible to use that script. Suggestions are welcome on the subjects as I'm less than experienced with DBs and feel like a moose on the ice.

My config: 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.50.4000.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.5466
Operating System 6.1.7601

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What verion of SQL are you using?  The syntax you have will only work in 2012 onwards

Instead you should execute the sp_addrolemember:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'Sales', 'Barry'
```

Comment: Please see edit regarding the version. One would think that the version I'm using to create the script **is** compatible with itself...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember 'Sales', 'Barry'
```

Comment: Sure but WHY does MS give the examples? What do they mean? When are they useful? I got that statement when I scripted out the database already in existence. Conclusion is that MS's own scripting gives an output that's faulty. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I think you are looking at SQL Server 2014 Syntax, I dont know much about that other way, Maybe because it only new in Sql Server but I always use this system stored procedure easier to remember.

Comment: Please see edit regarding the version. One would think that the version I'm using to create the script **is** compatible with itself...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `EXEC sp_addrolemember N'Sales', N'Barry'`